# Is it possible to use universal link to redirect user to a certain content if app is not installed?

Tags: ios, mobile, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

So, if user clicks on a link and the app is not installed, user will be redirected to the app store to download it. After it's downloaded, user opens the app and get redirected to a certain content depending on the link. I know it is possible if the app is already downloaded, but is it possible if it's not downloaded, without using third parties?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible without using 3rd parties like branch.io. You can find more solutions by searching this issue as **Deferred Deep Link**.